# cp directories and files, preserving directories and overwriting files

Tags: command-line, files, cp

I have a directory structure like this: **dirHome** and inside of it I have **dir1**, **dir2**, **dir3**.
All of these directories (**dir1**, **dir2**, **dir3**) each have 3 files inside: file1, file2, file3.
I have another copy of **dirHome** called **dirHome2** which has the exact same directory structure, but inside of the **dir1**, **dir2**, **dir3** it has 4 files instead: file1, file2, file3, file4.

I want to copy **dirHome** into **dirHome2**, keeping the directory structure as it is, overwriting the files that duplicate (file1, file2, file3) and keeping the files that do not exist in **dirHome** but exist in **dirHome2** (file4).

Comment: As of now, dirHome and dirHome2 are exact copies of one another, except the fact that dirHome2 has those extra files. However, if dirHome does have new directories that dirHome2 does not have, I want them to be copied over to dirHome2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cp` or `rsync`. I usually use `rsync` for this kind of task as `rsync` will by default overwrite files with same names on destination upon checking the size and modification time:

```
rsync -av dirHome/ dirHome2/
```

If the files to be overwritten are of the same size and have the same modification timestamp, then you can overwrite them forcefully by using the `--ignore-times` option:

```
rsync -av --ignore-times dirHome/ dirHome2/
```

Comment: I will try this right now, seems awesome! Had no idea something like rsync existed.